# Possible to run commands in a screen through cron jobs?

Tags: linux, cron, gnu-screen

I currently have an application running in a screen. I would like to run some commands in the screen through a cron job but would like to know if this is possible.

Using CentOS

Comment: Why? (What are you trying to accomplish.  State your end goal, not intermediate ones.)

Answer (score 1):

Screen manpage says that

```
-d -m
    Start screen in detached mode. This creates a new session but doesn't
    attach to it. This is useful for system startup scripts.
```